# What is an alternative to 'pre-' vs. 'post-' or 'before' vs 'after' that sorts in the order of events?

Tags: word-order

If ordered alphabetically , `pre` goes after `post`, because the 2nd character **r** of `pre` goes after the 2nd character **o** of `post`.  Same issue with `before` and `after` because of their 1st characters.  Is there an alternative to these pairings that, if ordered alphabetically, would place the equivalent of `pre` or `before` before its counterpart `post` or `after`?  Like in Spanish, '**a**ntes' vs. '***d***espues', but in English (`antes` means `before` and `despues` means `after`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **ante**- [prefix meaning 'before'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ante)
- **post** - [prefix meaning 'after'](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/post)

These days most commonly found as "ante-meridiem" (or a.m.), meaning before noon and "post meridiem" (or p.m.) meaning after noon.